# How to retrieve result Object of a wait.until(ExpectedConditons.or(...))

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-testing

I have three ExpectedConditions in an OR  statement inside a wait.until.  How do I retrieve the result of the whichever is successful?

```
ExpectedCondition<Object> result = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.or(
        ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(webElement1),
        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("messagebox")),
        ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()
    )
);
```

Comment: Good question... I didn't realize `or()` existed. BTW, `result` is of Type `boolean`.